How to add your own private keys to postfix configuration for DKIM without opendkim or the likes of it?
I have generated the keys locally through openssl added key.pub  to the DKIM DNS txt Record but how to add it to postfix withouth any other tool.Is there any connfiguration parameter where the file path can be specified or i need to through another tool as postfix lacks capabilities.

Postfix doesn't do dkim. It transports mail. You need to use a milter to sign messages. Opendkim is one well known milter for this purpose.

I surmised as when i read the postfix docs it mentioned the same ill add the link . http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html.
